# syslog port for serial comm port

Tags: logging

I have Cisco 3750 switch which is connected via console comm5 port to my laptop and in the same laptop I have installed a kiwi Sys log server. I have done all the configurations to log all my messages to the server but it isnot logging anything ? The default port number to which server is listening to is UDP 69 ? Is it the port number issue or something else ?

Comment: UDP/69 is the default port for TFTP, not for syslog. The serial console port on a Cisco switch cannot be used for syslogging, it's used for console access, so this will not work as you expect it to work.

Comment: Default port for syslog server is UDP/514. You will need L3 connectivity between your laptop and switch to obtain logs.

Comment: how to get that L3 connectivity ?

Comment: @Tahreekhan, connect your laptop to switch using patchcord, set IP address on switch, set address from same network as switch on your laptop network card settings, configure syslog to your PC host, run syslog software on laptop.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The serial console connection does not provide network connectivity and syslog requires a network connection. In other words, the switch can't talk to a syslog server running on the same machine as the terminal unless there's an additional network connection.

You need to connect and configure both laptop and switch to enable them to talk to each other. In the most basic configuration, both use the same subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.1/24 and 192.168.0.2/24) but it's also possible to connect them across one or more routers.

The only thing you can do on the serial console is to set your terminal software to log output to a file. Additionally, you can instruct the switch to output desired log items to the console with e.g. `logging console informational`. This isn't syslog, of course, but something similar.